# OpenVPN how can one client access a port on another client

Tags: openvpn

I have two devices connected to to the same OpenVPN server. Inter client communication is enabled.

Device A private IP: 172.27.224.2

Device B private IP: 172.27.224.3

I can ping from A to B and vice versa.

On device A I have a website running on port 3000. But if I open 172.27.224.2:3000 from device B, I get a connection time out.

Also if I access device A from B over the wifi network address (192.168.18.22:3000) it works.

How do I access this website from device B?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I access this website from device B?

Exactly the way you did.

Check firewalls on parts of the path. Ping uses ICMP, http uses TCP. Ping may work, while TCP port 3000 is blocked at some point along the path.

Comment: I have tried it with an inbound rule added to the windows firewall on A. Also I have added some more information about how it works fine over the wifi network (with and without the inbound rule). So it can't be a port issue right?

Comment: Ok. Have you verified that the packets arrive by e.g. using wireshark? Does the service listen to the OpenVPN interface?

Comment: No, should I run wireshark on A or B?
I'm not sure, how do I check if it's listening?

Comment: You should run it on A, to check if packets from B arrives. To check if it listens, try netstat. I've never used windows, so I have no idea about the syntax for netstat on that platform tho